# Detener delay sin time.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, hilos, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy intentando hacer una gui que controlan el mismo relay pero con tiempos diferentes, en su momento va a funcionar con una app android conectada por bluetooth.

De momento cada boton tiene que accionar un relay pero antes de esto tiene que esperar unos segundos para que se escuche la mp3, despues tiene que arrancar el relay, por ejemplo el primero 5 minutos , el segundo 10 etc. Todo funciona bien pero el ultimo boton ,el load7 tiene que ser el stop. No me deja hacer nada ya que el programa con el time.sleep se congela.

¿Hay alguna otra opcion? No estoy relacionada con los threads.

**Código**:

```
import sys
import serial
import bluetooth
import socket
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import resclean
from time import sleep
import time
from playsound import playsound
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/pi/Proba.mp3")
from threading import Thread

load1=18
load2=18
load3=18
load4=18
load5=18
load6=18
load7=18

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setwarnings(False)



gpio.setup(18,gpio.OUT)
gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)




class industrial(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(industrial,self).__init__()
        loadUi('Go.ui',self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Go')
        self.load_1.clicked.connect(self.load1)
        self.load_2.clicked.connect(self.load2)
        self.load_3.clicked.connect(self.load3)
        self.load_4.clicked.connect(self.load4)
        self.load_5.clicked.connect(self.load5)
        self.load_6.clicked.connect(self.load6)
        self.load_7.clicked.connect(self.load7)
    
@pyqtSlot()


def load1(self):
    if gpio.input(load1):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        self.load_1.setText('OFF')
    
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep(5)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.HIGH)
        self.load_1.setText('On')
        time.sleep(300)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        
def load2(self):
    if gpio.input(load2):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        self.load_2.setText('OFF')
    
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep(60)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.HIGH)
        self.load_2.setText('On')
        time.sleep(600)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)        
        
def load3(self):
    if gpio.input(load3):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        self.load_3.setText('OFF')
    
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep(60)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.HIGH)
        self.load_3.setText('On')
        time.sleep(900)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        
def load4(self):
    if gpio.input(load4):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        self.load_4.setText('OFF')
    
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep(60)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.HIGH)
        self.load_4.setText('On')
        time.sleep(1200)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        
def load5(self):
    if gpio.input(load_5):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        self.load_5.setText('OFF')
    
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep(60)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.HIGH)
        self.load_5.setText('On')
        time.sleep(1500)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        
        
def load6(self):
    if gpio.input(load6):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        self.load_6.setText('OFF')
    
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        time.sleep(60)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.HIGH)
        self.load_6.setText('On')
        time.sleep(1800)
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
        
def load7(self):
    if gpio.input(load7):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)
    
     
finally:

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
widget=industrial()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido/a a stackoverflow en español. Veo que tienes el código mal indentado. Edita, por favor, la pregunta y corrígelo para ayudar con la visualización de este.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "se congela"? ¿Ningun botón funciona o solo el 7?

Comment: No funciona ningun boton. Pero creo que es mas complicado de lo que parece. Por lo que veo cualquier loop , basicamente lo que hace es poner el programa en espera, lo que no te deja hacer nada. La unica opcion que he encontrado es de locos pero funciona. En la GUI cada boton es una conexion de subprocess hacis todos los loop que estan separados en ficheros .py .

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot 
from PyQt5 import Qt 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QDialog 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import resclean
from time import sleep
import time
import subprocess
import serial
import bluetooth
import socket
from playsound import playsound
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/pi/Proba.mp3")
from threading import Thread

load1=18
load2=18
load3=18
load4=18
load5=18
load6=18
load7=18

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setwarnings(False)



gpio.setup(18,gpio.OUT)
gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)




class industrial(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(industrial,self).__init__()
        loadUi('Go.ui',self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Go')
        self.load_1.clicked.connect(self.load1)
        self.load_2.clicked.connect(self.load2)
        self.load_3.clicked.connect(self.load3)
        self.load_4.clicked.connect(self.load4)
        self.load_5.clicked.connect(self.load5)
        self.load_6.clicked.connect(self.load6)
        self.load_7.clicked.connect(self.load7)
    
    @pyqtSlot()


    def load1(self):
         subprocess.Popen(["python3", 
"cincomin.py"])
```

Y la funcion de loop de cada fichero .py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
from time import sleep
import time
from time import sleep
import subprocess
import serial
import socket
from playsound import playsound
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/pi/Proba.mp3")
from threading import Thread

load1=18

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setwarnings(False)


gpio.setup(18,gpio.OUT)
gpio.output(18,gpio.LOW)




class industrial(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(industrial,self).__init__()
        while True:
              pygame.mixer.music.play()
              time.sleep(30)
              gpio.output(18,True)
              time.sleep(1200)
              gpio.output(18,False)
              break
        
              
              
    


    
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
widget=industrial()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Lo que he pensado es hacer el load 7 que va a ser el boton de stop con relay aparte y que corte la coriente del otro. Por lo menos me deja hacerlo, de la otra manera no deja hacer nada. Gracias

Comment: Si alguien tiene solucion de como dar funcion al boton stop de kill subprocess seria genial. Gracias

Comment: Podrias poner solo el codigo que es relevante, algo minimo? Es mucho codigo para leer. Lo mismo aplica para el codigo inicial en la pregunta. Esto deberia ir en tu pregunta, no como una respuesta.